# Save and Load Excel Slicer Cache

Tags: vba, excel, caching, slicers

I came across a simple piece of VBA to inspect slicer cache all active Slicers within an Excel Workbook.

```
Sub RetrieveSlicers()
Dim caches As Excel.SlicerCaches
Set caches = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
End Sub
```

By placing a break-point next to `End Sub`, right clicking on `cache` and selecting 'Add Watch...'

*(See below)*

[image]

You can view all of the items within every active slicer via the 'Watches' window.

[image]

My question is, can I save slicer cache information (specifically SlicerItems) for later (maybe as a text array?), and then load this saved slicer cache back into the slicers (re-populate slicers with saved SlicerItems)?

[image]

Example below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm sure as easy as it is to **get** Slicer Cache data, it'll be just as easy to **set** Slicer Cache data.

Any help as always is much appreciated.

Mr. J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (I don't have anything to test at the moment) :

```
Sub Save_Slicers()
Dim SliCaches As Excel.SlicerCaches
Dim SliCache As Excel.SlicerCache
Dim SliCName As String
Dim sliIt As Excel.SlicerItem
Dim A()
ReDim A(1 To 3, 1 To 1)

A(1, 1) = "Slicer Cache Name"
A(2, 1) = "Slicer Item Name"
A(3, 1) = "Selected"
ReDim Preserve A(LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1), LBound(A, 2) To UBound(A, 2) + 1)

Set SliCaches = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
For Each SliCache In SliCaches
    SliCName = SliCache.Name
    For Each sliIt In SliCache.SlicerItems
        A(1, UBound(A, 2)) = SliCName
        A(2, UBound(A, 2)) = sliIt.Name
        A(3, UBound(A, 2)) = sliIt.Selected
        ReDim Preserve A(LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1), LBound(A, 2) To UBound(A, 2) + 1)
    Next sliIt
Next SliCache
ReDim Preserve A(LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1), LBound(A, 2) To UBound(A, 2) - 1)

'Print it in a sheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(A, 2), UBound(A, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(A)
End Sub
```

Same one with a  manual slicer cache selector :

```
Sub Save_Selected_Slicers()
Dim SliCaches As Excel.SlicerCaches
Dim SliCache As Excel.SlicerCache
Dim SliCName As String
Dim sliIt As Excel.SlicerItem
Dim SaveSlice As Single
Dim A()
ReDim A(1 To 3, 1 To 1)

A(1, 1) = "Slicer Cache Name"
A(2, 1) = "Slicer Item Name"
A(3, 1) = "Selected"
ReDim Preserve A(LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1), LBound(A, 2) To UBound(A, 2) + 1)

Set SliCaches = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
For Each SliCache In SliCaches
    SliCName = SliCache.Name
    SaveSlice = MsgBox("Do you want to save " & SliCName & " ?", vbYesNo, "Save slicers")
    If SaveSlice <> vbYes Then
    Else
        For Each sliIt In SliCache.SlicerItems
            A(1, UBound(A, 2)) = SliCName
            A(2, UBound(A, 2)) = sliIt.Name
            A(3, UBound(A, 2)) = sliIt.Selected
            ReDim Preserve A(LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1), LBound(A, 2) To UBound(A, 2) + 1)
        Next sliIt
    End If
Next SliCache
ReDim Preserve A(LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1), LBound(A, 2) To UBound(A, 2) - 1)
'Print it in a sheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(A, 2), UBound(A, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(A)
End Sub
```

And load :

```
Sub Load_Slicers()
Dim SliCaches As Excel.SlicerCaches
Dim SliCache As Excel.SlicerCache
Dim sliIt As Excel.SlicerItem
Dim i As Double
Dim A()
'Load the array you printed
A = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value


Set SliCaches = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
For i = LBound(A, 1) To UBound(A, 1)
    For Each SliCache In SliCaches
        If SliCache.Name <> A(i, 1) Then
        Else
            For Each sliIt In SliCache.SlicerItems
                If sliIt.Name <> A(i, 2) Then
                Else
                    sliIt.Selected = A(i, 3)
                End If
            Next sliIt
        End If
    Next SliCache
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I am getting a Runtime error (Type mismatch) running the Load macro with this line of code: `A = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`

Comment: @Mr.J : My bad! I forgot the `.Value` to make it an Array instead of a Range! Edited it! ;)

Comment: That works a treat for my 'fruit' example. I've just tried it on a slightly larger file with 7 Slicers and hundreds of Slicer Items between them, and I'm getting an 'Out of memory' error. Is there a way to run this for a single slicer?.. (less stress on my computer)

Comment: @Mr.J : I added a Msgbox for you to choose which slicercaches you want to save! ;) You could also try to put a limitation on the `SlicerItems.Count` to avoid storing some data and that memory issue!

Comment: I've just left the office so I'll try the MsgBox addition in the morning but that sounds perfect! For others wanting a similar solution for a slightly smaller amount of data, the SaveAll/LoadAll works just great too. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through SlicerItems or PivotItems is really slow - and I've written a post that examines the bottlenecks that I recommend you take a look at:
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/

Here's another approach, that will be a *heck* of a lot faster on big pivots. Let's call your original PivotTable ptOriginal.

1. Make a copy of ptOriginal and place it in a hidden sheet. Let's call it ptTemp
2. Remove all fields from it apart from the one of interest. Let's call it pfTemp.
3. Disconnect it from the Slicer.
4. Add a new Slicer on that field. Let's call it slrTemp

When you want to restore the settings at a later date, connect slrTemp to ptOriginal.

This works, because Excel rationalizes the SlicerCaches behind the scenes, and keeps the settings from the one you just changed the connections on. See my article at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2014/08/05/slicers-and-slicercaches/ for more on this.